# Why is the output of below code related to struct and pointers as follows?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

New to C here, asking why the o/p of below code is as below

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct a{
    int a;
} A;

void func ( A* x)
{
    printf("2. %d\n",x->a);
    A* y = (A*) malloc (sizeof(A));
    y->a = 10;
    x = y; 
    printf("3. %d\n",x->a);
}

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    A* a1 = (A*) malloc (sizeof(A));
    a1->a=5;
    printf("1. %d\n",a1->a);
    func (a1);
    printf("4. %d\n",a1->a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

1. 5
2. 5
3. 10
4. 5

I am expecting the 4th printf value to be 10 since I am passing a pointer to func and I am executing x = y in func so that x also points to the object pointed by y, but outside func a1 is still pointing to its original object.
Why is this happening and how can I modify code so that a1 points to the new object created in func ?
Could anyone please help

Comment: All function parameters are passed by value in C. That means `x` is a local variable in the function and setting it does not set the caller's variable.

Comment: @kaylum But I am passing a pointer which is passed by reference to function in C right?

Comment: You can change what it points to by derefencing but you can't change the original pointer variable itself. Basically you are passing _a copy_ of the address to the function.